Cloud Files API - explorer.exe locking folders and prevents rename
We are implementing a cloud sync engine using the cloud files API.
Everything is working more or less as expected.
However if I create a folder hierarchy of 2 or more folders, say folder A has a child folder B which has another child folder C.
Whenever I open folder C in the file explorer I am no longer able to rename, delete or move folder A.
It states The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program.
It does not happen when opening folder A but only when navigating into folder C.
No files are present in the folders, only the folder hierarchy and it happens every time and can be reproduced 100% on my end.
This also happens on our customers system as well as our QA systems.

I checked the open handles using Powertoys File Locksmith and the Resource Monitor and only explorer.exe has open handles on the folder and subfolders.

If I restart explorer.exe the folder can be changed again. It also sometimes works just closing the file explorer window I used to open the directory.
This is also an issue with OneDrive, so I can assume it has nothing to do with our own implementation of the cloud files API?
Also, this only happens when interacting with folders below a sync root and not on the "regular" file system.
I am using Windows 10.0.19045. The same issue can not be reproduced on Windows 11 (10.0.22621).
